# How can I play the levels I created to a world in Super Mario Maker?

Tags: super-mario-maker

I have created four levels in Super Marion Maker - they form a world. Nintendo says on their site that you simply press the play icon. I do not see any "play" icon anywhere. I can only play the levels in "edit" mode. I want to play them with three lives as one world.

Can anyone help me?

Screen shots would be appreciated because I've seen too many places that I should press the play icon - and obviously I am not able to find it.

Comment: If it's possible to play them as one world, that will be news to me too. AFAIK you can only play each level individually, in the way described in Rai Zarek's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The place to play your own worlds or levels is somewhat hidden. You have to open the main menu (upper right corner) and click the Course Bot icon in it's lower left corner.